# Accessing file on team drive using team_drive_get

Tags: r

I have used googledrive functions successfully to access xlsx spreadsheets on my own google drive - so

```
drive_download(file = "DIRECTOR_TM/Faculty/Faculty Productivity/Faculty productivity.xlsx", 
   overwrite=TRUE)
```

works and saves a local copy of the file for me to run analyses on.

Mid year we switched to using team drives and the equivalent

```
drive_download(file = "Director/Faculty/Faculty Productivity/Faculty productivity.xlsx", 
   overwrite=TRUE)
```

doesn't work - I get an error that says "Error: 'file' does not identify at least one Drive file."

So I have tried using the team_drive_get function - and am confused

```
Director <- team_drive_get("Director")
```

does work - I get a tribble with one observation.  But the file I want is in a subdirectory in the "Director" team drive.  So I tried

```
TeamDrive <- team_drive_get("Director/Faculty/Faculty Productivity/")
```

but the result is a 0 obs tribble.

How do I get access to a file in a subdirectory on a team drive?

Answer (score 1):

`googledrive` uses IDs to identify objects in a flattened file structure for your team, i.e., you don't need to know the subdirectory. If you know the name of your file, you just need to search the team drive and find the ID (see your specific question---and why I found this---addressed below).

```
# environment variables
FILENAME <- "your_file_name" 
TEAM_DRIVE_NAME <- "your_team_name_here"

# get file(s)
gdrive_files_df <- drive_find(team_drive = TEAM_DRIVE_NAME)
drive_download(
    as_id(gdrive_files_df[gdrive_files_df$name == FILENAME,]$id),
    overwrite = TRUE
)
```

Alternatively, this is what you can do if you *do* need to find the specific ID of a subdirectory (perhaps for an upload where there is no existing ID for the file).

```
# environment variables
FILEPATH <- "your_file_path"
TEAM_SUBDIRECTORY <- "your_subdirectory"

# grab the ID of your subdirectory and upload to that directory
drive_upload(
    FILEPATH,
    path = as_id(gdrive_files_df[gdrive_files_df$name == TEAM_SUBDIRECTORY,]$id), 
    name = FILENAME,
)
```